# Problema con List <string>

Tags: c#, lista

Hola tengo un problema al intentar modificar un código de un analizador léxico y quiero que identifique palabras reservadas. El código original venía con `List<char>` pero cuando cambio los `char` por `string` me surge un error en esta parte:

```
List<string> _elementos = txtExpresion.Text.Replace(" ","").ToCharArray().ToList();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la verdad no se cómo resolver eso.

```
public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
{

    List<string> _numeros = new List<string>(new string[] { "0","1"});
    List<string> _variables = new List<string>(new string[] { "a"});
    List<string> _operadores = new List<string>(new string[] { "+" });
    List<string> _palabras = new List<string>(new string[] { "definir" });
    List<string> _delimitadores = new List<string>(new string[] { "(" });
    DataTable _tblResultados = new DataTable();

    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tblResultados.Columns.Add("Token", typeof(string));
        _tblResultados.Columns.Add("Tipo", typeof(string));
    }      

    private void btnAnalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tblResultados.Clear();

        List<string> _elementos = txtExpresion.Text.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray().ToList();

        if (_elementos.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow _fila;

            foreach (string elemento in _elementos)
            {
                _fila = _tblResultados.NewRow();

                if (_numeros.Contains(elemento))
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Número";
                }
                else if (_variables.Contains(elemento))
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Variable";
                }
                else if (_operadores.Contains(elemento))
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Operador";
                }
                else if (_delimitadores.Contains(elemento))
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Delimitador";
                }
                else if (_palabras.Contains(elemento))
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Palabras";
                }
                else
                {
                    _fila["Token"] = elemento;
                    _fila["Tipo"] = "Error";
                }

                _tblResultados.Rows.Add(_fila);
            }

            dgvResultados.DataSource = _tblResultados;
            dgvResultados.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            dgvResultados.DataSource = null;
            dgvResultados.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: El método ToList() convierte el texto en el control textExpresion en una lista de caracteres, siempre va a devolver un List de tipo char, porque necesitas almacenarlo a una lista de string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes usar la función split (le pasas como parámetro el separador, osea espacio en blanco) para obtener el array de palabras y castear a list

```
List<string> _elementos = txtExpresion.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Comment: me funciono muy bien ,gracias por tu ayuda!!